# can attributes be hidden in a simplexmlobject?

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I have this simplexml object and it looks fine, but when i convert a part of it... like:
$xmlMeshHeading = $MeshHeading->asXML();

I suddenly get attributes which i can't find in the simple XML object...?
Here are some parts of the two files:

```
SimpleXMLObject:

[MeshHeadingList] => SimpleXMLElement Object [DescriptorName] => Acoustic Stimulation 
                                (
                                    [MeshHeading] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                (

                                                    [QualifierName] => methods
                                                )

                                            [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                (
                                                    [DescriptorName] => Adolescent
                                                )

                                            [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                (
                                                    [DescriptorName] => Age Factors
                                                )

                                            [3] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                (
                                                    [DescriptorName] => Child
                                                )

                                            [4] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                (
                                                    [DescriptorName] => Electromyography
                                                    [QualifierName] => methods
                                                )

                                            [5] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                (
                                                    [DescriptorName] => Female
                                                )

                                            [6] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                (
                                                    [DescriptorName] => Galvanic Skin Response
                                                    [QualifierName] => physiology
                                                )

                                            [7] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                (
                                                    [DescriptorName] => Humans
                                                )

                                            [8] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                (
                                                    [DescriptorName] => Male
                                                )

                                            [9] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                (
                                                    [DescriptorName] => Muscle, Skeletal
                                                    [QualifierName] => physiology
                                                )

                                            [10] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                (
                                                    [DescriptorName] => Probability
                                                )

                                            [11] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                (
                                                    [DescriptorName] => Reaction Time
                                                    [QualifierName] => physiology
                                                )

                                            [12] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                (
                                                    [DescriptorName] => Sex Factors
                                                )

                                            [13] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                (
                                                    [DescriptorName] => Startle Reaction
                                                    [QualifierName] => physiology
                                                )
```

And here the asXML file it's from the same source...:

```
 <MeshHeadingList>
            <MeshHeading>
                <DescriptorName MajorTopicYN="N">Acoustic Stimulation</DescriptorName>
                <QualifierName MajorTopicYN="N">methods</QualifierName>
            </MeshHeading>

            <MeshHeading>
                <DescriptorName MajorTopicYN="N">Adolescent</DescriptorName>
            </MeshHeading>
            <MeshHeading>
                <DescriptorName MajorTopicYN="N">Age Factors</DescriptorName>
            </MeshHeading>
            <MeshHeading>
                <DescriptorName MajorTopicYN="N">Child</DescriptorName>

            </MeshHeading>
            <MeshHeading>
                <DescriptorName MajorTopicYN="N">Electromyography</DescriptorName>
                <QualifierName MajorTopicYN="Y">methods</QualifierName>
            </MeshHeading>
            <MeshHeading>
                <DescriptorName MajorTopicYN="N">Female</DescriptorName>

            </MeshHeading>
            <MeshHeading>
                <DescriptorName MajorTopicYN="N">Galvanic Skin Response</DescriptorName>
                <QualifierName MajorTopicYN="N">physiology</QualifierName>
            </MeshHeading>
            <MeshHeading>
                <DescriptorName MajorTopicYN="N">Humans</DescriptorName>

            </MeshHeading>
            <MeshHeading>
                <DescriptorName MajorTopicYN="N">Male</DescriptorName>
            </MeshHeading>
            <MeshHeading>
                <DescriptorName MajorTopicYN="N">Muscle, Skeletal</DescriptorName>
                <QualifierName MajorTopicYN="Y">physiology</QualifierName>

            </MeshHeading>
            <MeshHeading>
                <DescriptorName MajorTopicYN="N">Probability</DescriptorName>
            </MeshHeading>
            <MeshHeading>
                <DescriptorName MajorTopicYN="N">Reaction Time</DescriptorName>
                <QualifierName MajorTopicYN="N">physiology</QualifierName>

            </MeshHeading>
            <MeshHeading>
                <DescriptorName MajorTopicYN="N">Sex Factors</DescriptorName>
            </MeshHeading>
            <MeshHeading>
                <DescriptorName MajorTopicYN="N">Startle Reaction</DescriptorName>
                <QualifierName MajorTopicYN="Y">physiology</QualifierName>

            </MeshHeading>
        </MeshHeadingList>
```

My question is...
1. Is there a function to "unhide" the attributes in SimpleXML?
OR
2. How can i get stuff from an XML file, like attributes and the values...?

Best,
Thijs

Comment: What is `$MeshHeading`? explain the calling in your question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Attributes are only returned when accessing a specific node. Per example:

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<xml><foo bar="baz">hello world</foo></xml>');
print_r($xml);
```

Outputs:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [foo] => hello world
)
```

While this:

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<xml><foo bar="baz">hello world</foo></xml>');
print_r($xml->foo);
```

Outputs:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [@attributes] => Array
        (
            [bar] => baz
        )

    [0] => hello world
)
```

It's probably because of the internal structure of `SimpleXMLElement`. Like many built-in objects in PHP (DOMDocument, etc.), most properties aren't printed out when using `print_r` on them. For SimpleXML attributes, `print_r` won't display them unless you access a node, because it will overload to `__get` (kind of).

Comment: `print_r()` does display private properties. It doesn't display all the attributes simply because SimpleXML does a lot of things "just in time" and reading a node's attribute must be one of them.

Answer (score 1):

`print_r()` is simply not the right tool to inspect `SimpleXMLElement` objects.

If you want to know what's inside of one, just use `->asXML()` on it and read it in XML. 100% of its nodes and attributes are always available despite not being displayed by `print_r()` or `var_dump()`.